# Extract substring from urls stored in a pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

Pandas column contains a series of `urls`. I'd like to extract a substring from the url.
MRE code below.

```
s = pd.Series(['https://url-location/img/xxxyyy_image1.png'])

s.apply(lambda x: x[x.find("/")+1:st.find("_")])
```

I'd like to extract `xxxyyy` and store them into a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
>>> s.str.extract(r'.*/([^_]+)')
        0
0  xxxyyy
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4w4aKr/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/` - a slash
- `([^_]+)` - Capturing group 1 (the value captured into this group will be the actual return value of `Series.str.extract`): one or more chars other than `_` char.

Comment: how does it skip over `/img` and know to look at the one `_` in the substring?

Comment: @kms `.*` is a greedily quantified pattern, it grabs the whole string at first. The engine starts backtracking then, trying to match some text with the subsequent patterns. So the `/` char found is the last `/` char that is followed by one or more chars other than `_`. The `[^_]` is a negated character class, it matches any char other than a `_` char, so it cannot match across more `_`s, it will stop before the first `_` or end of string. Here is [my YT video about backtracking in regex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDWK_tK2LUE).

Answer (score 1):

Also possible:

```
s.str.split('/').str[-1].str.split('_').str[0]
# Out[224]: xxxyyy
```

This works, because `.str` allows for the slice annotation.
So `.str[-1]` will provide the last element after the split for example.